# How to sort an InstrumentedList based on timestamp?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Currently I have an `InstrumentedList` that represents a one-to-many relationship in my pyramid app. The relationship is constructed in the following way:

```
Class project:
 submissions = relationship('Submission', backref='project')
```

I want to iterate over every submission in a list of projects. However, I want my submissions to be ordered by timestamp (a `datetime` object)

Here is how I am iterating over my submissions at the moment:

```
for project in projects:
    for submission in project.submissions:
        # Do some stuff with each submission here
```

The problem is that the order of my submissions for every project changes whenever the app is reloaded. I need the order to be consistent and ordered by timestamp, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I dont see any timestamp but you could do `sorted_list=sorted(orig_list,key=lambda x:x['timestamp'])` or something very simillar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to specify an ordering in your relationship definition, using the [`order_by` parameter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#relationships-api):

```
class Project(Base):
    # ...
    submissions = relationship('Submission',
        backref='Project', order_by='Submission.timestamp')
```

Answer (score 1):

@martjin answer is completely ok , but if you want to order your table in **descending order**, then use **desc()** function:

```
class Project(Base):
    # ...
    submissions = relationship('Submission',
        backref='Project', order_by='Submission.timestamp.desc()')
```